# Building Qt WebEngine on Windows without Visual Studio 2017

Tags: windows, visual-studio, qt, build, qtwebengine

I would like to build Qt 5.12 from source including Qt WebEngine on Windoww 10 (64 bit). According to the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/qtwebengine-platform-notes.html), Visual Studio 2017 is needed for that task which I cannot use due to limitations of other libraries involved.

I'm stuck to Visual Studio 2015. Possible options could be clang or an intel compiler. Building Qt myself is necessary because some patches have to be applied.

Did anybody succeed with that ?

When Qt is configured, there do not seem to be options to enable/disable WebEngine explicitly. Instead, the compilation of this module is simply skipped without further message if the compiler does not match.

My configuration so far:

```
configure.bat ^
 -prefix !DESTINATION! ^
 -opensource ^
 -confirm-license ^
 -platform win32-msvc2015 ^
 -release ^
 -force-debug-info ^
 -system-zlib ^
 -openssl-runtime ^
 -qt-libpng ^
 -qt-libjpeg ^
 -qt-sqlite ^
 -sql-odbc ^
 -sql-sqlite ^
 -no-gif ^
 -nomake tests -nomake examples ^
 -no-dbus ^
 -no-opengl ^
 -icu ^
 -webengine-printing-and-pdf ^
 "ICU_PREFIX=!ICUDIR!" ^
 "ZLIB_PREFIX=!INTEL_ZLIB_DIR!" ^
 "ZLIB_LIBS=-lzlib" ^
 "OPENSSL_PREFIX=!OPENSSLDIR!" ^
 "OPENSSL_LIBS=-llibssl -llibcrypto"
```

Comment: Checking the source there is [this](https://github.com/qt/qtwebengine/blob/c6fb532d81f405b2456c382aa0b29eef8866f993/src/core/config/windows.pri#L57) line, you could try to change that and see if it works.